# How to open port 3000 on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have seen many questions related or same as mine but I am not able to get the right answer.

I am developing the node js application and hosted on AWS. But I am not able to open the port 3000.

I am checking if the port is open or not using the following command:

```
 netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
```

Security group:

In bound: 
[image: In bound]

Out bound:
[image: Out bound]

Comment: `netstat` does not test whether a port is "open."  It shows whether a service is *listening* on that port, and this is not impacted by security groups.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot then how do I check port is open or not?

Comment: Why do you think the port is not open?

Comment: ok when I was trying to access ip_address:3000 it says connection refused.

Comment: The port is open.  You have nothing listening on that port.  If your security group settings were not working, you'd get `Connection timed out`.

Comment: okay. Thanks @Michael-sqlbot

Answer (score 1):

Assuming NACL , Security Group and IP Tables are configured correctly.

I had faced similar problem with Node Once and Double Checked every setting , at last I found out **A node service has to be attached to that port** in order for it to work.

*Even if the port is open it will not show open when you ping unless you have service attached to it.*

You Can try something like `http.createServer(app).listen(3000)`

Hope it Helps!

Comment: how it will attach, by app.set('port', port) ??

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at your NACL; http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ACLs.html

Im assuming you have it running on an EC2 instance, if there is a firewall on the OS that allows port 3000?